# pdfpages not scaling the pdf when fitpaper is true

Tags: pdfpages, scale

I have created a pdf using the following tex code. its 400pt x 400pt size.

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=400pt:400pt,DIV=calc}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth =400pt,layoutheight =400pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Sampe Some text
\end{document}
```

The pdf snapshot

[image]

Now i am trying to fit it in a 600pt x 600pt pdf size and expecting it to auto scale to the size

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={600pt}{600pt},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{testing.pdf,1}
\end{document}
```

But the pdf shows as 400pt x 400pt inside 600pt x 600pt.

Snapshot of the pdf created

[image]

pdfpages documentation says `noautoscale=false` is defaut but with `fitpaper` option i see that does not work. Even if `noautoscale=false` is set it does not work and also it scales to 1 as default. Then Only way is to use the option `scale=`. There is no mention about the `scale=` option in the pdfpages manual. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With option `templatesize={600pt}{600pt}` you are telling pdfpages to create a page with 600 pt x 600 pt. And option `templatesize` will override option `fitpaper`. This is why you get a page with 600 pt x 600 pt. Thus don't use it if you don't want it.

Some further explanations:

- Option `fitpaper` uses the page dimensions of the first page that you include. Any further pages will get the same page dimensions.
- Sometimes the first page is a title page with special page dimensions and you might prefer to fit all pages accoding to the second page instead of the first page. This is when you use option `pagetemplate=2`.
- Only if there's no page with page dimensions that fit your needs, it is necessary to specify the page dimensions with option `templatesize`.

Comment: `And option templatesize will override option fitpaper` thanks for the explanation